# Error handling in onCall function and runTransaction not compatible

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have an issue with compatibility between Firestore transactions and Firebase onCall cloud functions. If I attempt to run a transaction and throw verification errors inside the callback, any thrown `HttpsErrors` become overwritten by the transaction failed promise chain. I cannot reorganise the promise chain as the transaction is not run in the `then` portion, rather the aforementioned callback.

```
  return db.runTransaction((transaction) => {
    const userRef = db.collection("users").doc(auth.uid);

    return transaction
      .get(userRef)
      .catch((error: HttpsError) => {
        logger.error("Failed to get user document.", error);
        throw error;
      })
      .then((userSnap) => {
        
        ...

        if (user.roles?.admin !== true) {
          logger.error("User is not admin.");
          throw new HttpsError(
            "permission-denied",
            "You are not admin."
          );
        }

        ...

      });
  })
  .catch((error: HttpsError) => {
    logger.error("Failed to commit transaction.", error);
    throw error;
  });
```

In the above case, if the user is not admin an `HttpsError` is thrown intending to notify the client, passing it to the catch on the transaction, which throws the appropriate `HttpsError`. This however, stops a failed transaction from being thrown. If I were to do this instead:

```
  .catch((error: Error) => {
    logger.error("Failed to commit transaction.", error);
    throw new HttpsError("internal", error.message);
  });
```

This would overwrite the manual error for the admin check. Am I missing a way to check for both? Or was this an edge case oversight.

I am also unsure if I am missing a better way to handle errors in callable cfs since promises and throws don't seem to work together too well.

Comment: Read the section of documentation that talks about [passing information out of transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#passing_information_out_of_transactions).  Your transaction handler will need to tell the code that runs the transaction to respond to errors coming from the transaction and correctly translate them into results for your function.

Comment: From what I'm understanding you're suggesting to type assert in the catch block to see whether it is an `HttpsError` or a native `Error`?

Comment: No. Just return a special item of data from your transaction handler, and check for that in the code that invokes it.  Then do whatever you need to do to signal the failure of the function.